# Studio Controls does not work on Ubuntu Studio

Tags: ubuntu-studio, jack

For quite some time the Studio Controls (2.3.1) app hasn't been able to start Jack. This started with some Ubuntu Studio upgrade. I think the two latest versions have acted like this. I'm now running version 22.04.

I have two audio interfaces, Behringer UCM1820 and a Native Instruments Audio 2 DJ gen 1. Qjackctl runs fine and I can use the computer with that luckily. Setting bridges etc. seems painful with that.

I have a HP Elitedesk I7 6700 and in the past before some major version updates everything worked fine.

```
5.15.0-50-lowlatency #56-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 21 13:57:05 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output from convert-studio-controls

```
Convert Studio Conrols Config File (version 2.3.1)
Search for: /home/kim/.config/autojack/autojack.json force: False
config file found, check it
checking config file for compatability with version 2.3.1
checking data base
Checking Devices
 Devices checked, continue data base check
write new config file
```

The output into autojack.log after trying to start JACK in Studio Controls (logging level extra):

```
2022-10-17 16:06:18,540 - AutoJack - INFO - Autojack started: logging started
2022-10-17 16:06:22,579 - AutoJack - DEBUG - check config file: Convert Studio Conrols Config File (version 2.3.1)
Search for: /home/kim/.config/autojack/autojack.json force: False
config file found, check it
checking config file for compatability with version 2.3.1
checking data base
Checking Devices
 Devices checked, continue data base check
write new config file
2022-10-17 16:06:22,579 - AutoJack - DEBUG - Checking for phones plugged in
2022-10-17 16:06:22,579 - AutoJack - Level 7 - log level: 7
2022-10-17 16:06:22,580 - AutoJack - Level 7 - Device scan found: 
2022-10-17 16:06:22,580 - AutoJack - Level 7 - Device scan found: UMC1820
2022-10-17 16:06:22,581 - AutoJack - Level 7 - {
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "log-level": "7",
    "jack": {
        "on": true,
        "driver": "alsa",
        "chan-in": 1,
        "chan-out": 1,
        "rate": 44100,
        "frame": 1024,
        "period": 3,
        "connect-mode": "n",
        "dev": "none",
        "usbdev": "USB1,0,0",
        "cap-latency": 0,
        "play-latency": 0
    },
    "extra": {
        "a2j": true,
        "usbauto": false,
        "usb-single": false,
        "monitor": "system:playback_1",
        "phone-action": "switch",
        "phone-device": "none",
        "usbnext": 2,
        "a2j_u": false
    },
    "pulse": {
        "inputs": {
            "pulse_in": {
                "connection": "system:capture_1",
                "count": 2
            }
        },
        "outputs": {
            "pulse_out": {
                "connection": "system:playback_1",
                "count": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "devices": {
        "USB1": {
            "number": 1,
            "usb": true,
            "internal": false,
            "hdmi": false,
            "firewire": false,
            "rates": [
                "44100",
                "48000",
                "88200",
                "96000"
            ],
            "min_latency": 32,
            "id": "1397:0503",
            "bus": "001",
            "sub": {
                "0": {
                    "name": "UMC1820,0,0",
                    "playback": true,
                    "capture": true,
                    "rate": 44100,
                    "frame": 1024,
                    "nperiods": 3,
                    "hide": false,
                    "cap-latency": 0,
                    "play-latency": 0,
                    "play-chan": 100,
                    "cap-chan": 100,
                    "play-pid": 0,
                    "cap-pid": 0
                }
            },
            "raw": "UMC1820"
        },
        "": {
            "number": 0,
            "usb": false,
            "internal": false,
            "hdmi": false,
            "firewire": false,
            "min_latency": 16,
            "rates": [
                "32000",
                "44100",
                "48000",
                "88200",
                "96000",
                "192000"
            ],
            "raw": "",
            "id": "none",
            "bus": "none",
            "sub": {}
        }
    },
    "znet": {},
    "mnet": {
        "type": "jack",
        "count": 0
    }
}
2022-10-17 16:06:22,581 - AutoJack - Level 7 - Device scan found: 
2022-10-17 16:06:22,581 - AutoJack - Level 7 - Device scan found: UMC1820
```

So to me it seems that the app  just scans for interfaces and recognizes them but does not even seem to try to run JACK?

In Studio Controls "JACK Master Settings" tab, the drop down box for "JACK Master Device (no USB)" is grayed out, but in the "USB Device that should be Master" the correct interface "USB1 1397:0503 001 UMC1820,0,0 capture and playback" is selected.

Audio2DJ does not show in these logs since I deleted autojack.json in hopes of removing any effect it might have on this.

Contents of autojack.json right now

```
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "log-level": "7",
    "jack": {
        "on": true,
        "driver": "alsa",
        "chan-in": 1,
        "chan-out": 1,
        "rate": 44100,
        "frame": 1024,
        "period": 3,
        "connect-mode": "n",
        "dev": "none",
        "usbdev": "USB1,0,0",
        "cap-latency": 0,
        "play-latency": 0
    },
    "extra": {
        "a2j": true,
        "usbauto": false,
        "usb-single": false,
        "monitor": "system:playback_1",
        "phone-action": "switch",
        "phone-device": "none",
        "usbnext": 2,
        "a2j_u": false
    },
    "pulse": {
        "inputs": {
            "pulse_in": {
                "connection": "system:capture_1",
                "count": 2
            }
        },
        "outputs": {
            "pulse_out": {
                "connection": "monitor",
                "count": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "devices": {
        "USB1": {
            "number": 1,
            "usb": true,
            "internal": false,
            "hdmi": false,
            "firewire": false,
            "rates": [
                "44100",
                "48000",
                "88200",
                "96000"
            ],
            "min_latency": 32,
            "id": "1397:0503",
            "bus": "001",
            "sub": {
                "0": {
                    "name": "UMC1820,0,0",
                    "playback": true,
                    "capture": true,
                    "rate": 44100,
                    "frame": 1024,
                    "nperiods": 3,
                    "hide": false,
                    "cap-latency": 0,
                    "play-latency": 0,
                    "play-chan": 100,
                    "cap-chan": 100,
                    "play-pid": 0,
                    "cap-pid": 0
                }
            },
            "raw": "UMC1820"
        },
        "": {
            "number": 0,
            "usb": false,
            "internal": false,
            "hdmi": false,
            "firewire": false,
            "min_latency": 16,
            "rates": [
                "32000",
                "44100",
                "48000",
                "88200",
                "96000",
                "192000"
            ],
            "raw": "",
            "id": "none",
            "bus": "none",
            "sub": {}
        }
    },
    "znet": {},
    "mnet": {
        "type": "jack",
        "count": 0
    }
}
``
```

Comment: What upgrade did you perform?   In the [Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS Release notes](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/) it states "*Due to the change in desktop environment, direct upgrades to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS from versions prior to 21.10 are unsupported.*" and your issues maybe the expected results of breakage due to DE change.

Comment: This happened one major update before the latest update to Plasma, I can't now remember how the versions went before that. Before this I had the previous LTS, was it 20.04, and before that I'm not sure anymore. But the desktop environment stayed the same between the ones that broke it. It was the new version of Studio Controls that does not work anymore, (all V2 I believe), I suppose it was 1.x which still worked for me. I wonder if it's possible to roll back to it. But it's weird since Qjackctl works.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS required a re-install to go to 22.04 LTS. Yes the [Ubuntu release upgrader tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) on the base Ubuntu system you're running will offer & upgrade your system, but that breaks Ubuntu Studio which is why Ubuntu Studio said not to break it. To roll back is to use whatever backup strategy you put in place; so we can't know that. You may get help here on your issue; I'm only aware it was *unsupported* because of breakage in QA due to need to change many things with DE change, thus why the team said re-install.